# import can't be used in chrome 61?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to play ES6 features in the latest release version of chrome, that is chrome 61, and I met the error during using the `import` key word.
Technically, `import` is used as following method but the console showed me errors:

```
import Mymodule from "Mymodule.js"
```

the console printed:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I have already turn the following experimental features on:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony
chrome://flags/#enable-module-scripts
```

and following off:

```
chrome://flags/#disable-javascript-harmony-shipping
```

Comment: How are you including the script? `<script type="module">` is required

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-type-module-example-1

Comment: After adding `<script type="module">` I got this error:   `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'Mymodule'` @CodingIntrigue

Comment: I tried messing around with this too, noticed import is a valid keyword in the console but couldn't get it to work

Comment: https://matthewphillips.info/posts/loading-app-with-script-module

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that `from "Mymodule.js"`.

A module must be either a full URL (including a protocol), an absolute path (starting with /), or a relative path (starting with ./ or ../).

Any other strings are reserved for future use.

source: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#bare-import-specifiers-arent-currently-supported
(referenced from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/nic61#modules )

Comment: excelent answer to a picky issue,  hard to find any good documentation or answer.  Thanks @himdel.

Answer (score 0):

"import" support is not yet natively included in Chrome, but ***is*** currently in development

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5684934484164608

Until then you would need to compile and bundle your code with something like Babel and Browserify or Webpack.

**Update**: As mentioned below by @neaumusic, this feature is part of Chrome 61. The [What's New](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/devtools-release-notes#modules) note references [Paul Irish's Module-implementation](https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/) as an example.

It would help to see your MyModule.js code, to see exactly what it is your module is exporting. This partially determines how you phrase your 'import' statements.

Comment: There was an update to Chrome Devtools that specifically calls out importing

Comment: Interesting. I see Paul Irish's Module Implementation demo working in the browser just fine. Note I ref'd above said the feature was still 'In development'. Can you provide sample code for your Mymodule.js?

Comment: Refer to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ and trying hard, I found there settings named `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony` and `chrome://flags/#enable-module-scripts` in chrome should be `enabled`  to develop ES6-level JS.