# ES6 type="module" Crushes Syntax Error Stack Trace (Chrome 61)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, module, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484691/import-cant-be-used-in-chrome-61) suggests that Chrome 61 does not support ES6 Module loading but that seems to be contradicted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/devtools-release-notes#modules). Either way, that's not my question, since I seem to have it working in my current code.

The question is this: when I load a script with `type="module"` my stack trace on the loaded script disappears. For example:

```
index.html
---
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>

app.js
---
import ErrorModule from "../../modules/error-module.js"

error-module.js
--
//console.log"(syntax error");
throw new Error("thrown error");
```

With the above code, the thrown error works perfectly. However, if I uncomment the syntax error, my stack trace gets crushed, and all I see is this: [image: Not very helpful]

How can I get a full stack trace to hunt down these pesky syntax errors on Chrome 61 with modules?

Comment: Your log line has the quote in the wrong place, it is a syntax error on line 1, just like the error says.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I guess it would be the same even if bad import wasn't at line 1. Notice that syntax error were in error-module.js but it is shown in app.js, and line 1 is bogus `throw e`. This reveals interesting details about Chrome module implementation, I don't remember what the specs say about that)

Comment: It certainly seems less than ideal, but this stuff is still super new so I'm not that surprised.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - the point of the log line is to throw a syntax error, so it's a deliberate mistake. @estus is correct that it throws at line 1 regardless of where the error actually occurs, and that it throws from the `app.js` module rather than any sub module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been solved now that I have upgraded to Chrome 62, so it seems like it was a problem with Chrome's ES6 module implementation.